# Java - Tasks and Futures - Do I need to catch exceptions or can I leave them to the Application Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, concurrency, javafx-8

I'm writing a converter program using JavaFX, and am using the recommended `javafx.concurrent.Task` to do the heavy work away from the JavaFX Application Thread. I'm also using `java.util.concurrent.Future` and `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` within it to do extra work that can be done concurrently.

However a lot of the work involves methods that can potentially throw, and I need the process to stop in its tracks if that occurs. I'm currently spamming `try-catch` blocks everywhere and returning false rather than letting the exceptions bubble up.

But as `call()` in both `Future` and `Task` have the `throws Exception` declaration in case there are any uncaught ones, is it ok for me to just not catch the exceptions in the Futures and let them be handled by the Application Thread when the `Task` terminates?
As the exceptions will do what i want and terminate the thread, while providing extra information as to why the thread stopped to the application thread so i can show an appropriate alert.

The other reason I want to do this is within the Futures I need access to values from the `Task` thread, but i don't need to alter them so I'd like to make values `final` and create the Futures in lambdas. The `try-catch` blocks are complicating matters as i can't make as many values `final` (or effectively `final`) as I'd like. This is because I'm assigning the return values from methods that could potentially throw when i initialise them. As a result I have to surround the assignment in a `try-catch`, thus need to keep creating temp variables before copying them to a `final` variable, which makes the process look a mess and likely wastes memory.

Is not catching exceptions inside a `Task` or `Future` a good idea or not? Are there any major pitfalls or issues with not catching exceptions until the Application Thread?

Here's an example of what i currently have in my controller class to deal with the event that should trigger this process:

```
ExecutorService converterExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
ConverterTask converterThread = new ConverterTask()
converterExecutor.execute(converterThread);
Boolean success = null;
try
{
    success = converterThread.get();
}
catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e1)
{
    e1.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
if (success == null)
{
    return false;
}
```

And the `ConverterTask` class containing the long-running logic to me run in another thread

```
public class ConverterTask extends Task< Boolean >
{
    public Boolean call() throws Exception
    {
        //do stuff
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future< String > skeletonThread = executor.submit(new Callable< String >()
        {
            //stuff that can throw exceptions
        });
        //do more stuff
        String temp_sklData = null;
        try
        {
            temp_sklData = skeletonThread.get();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        if (temp_sklData == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        final String sklData = temp_sklData;
        //do more stuff including use sklData in a Lambda Future
    }
}
```

and what I'd like to do in `converterTask` instead if my propagating the exceptions is a good idea

```
public class converterTask extends Task< Boolean >
{
    public Boolean call() throws Exception
    {
        //do stuff
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future< String > skeletonThread = executor.submit(new Callable< String >()
        {
            //stuff that can throw exceptions
        });
        //do more stuff
        final String sklData = skeletonThread.get();
        //do more stuff including use sklData in a Lambda Future
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two executors?  Why are you executing a blocking future.get() on the JavaFX application thread?

Comment: @jewelsea This is early code, and I'm still finding my feet in JavaFX. I know i shouldn't bock on the application thread, but i was putting up with it until i found an alternative (which James_D provided when he told me about the state change handlers)
New to executors, how would you do it in that case? They're in different classes, and i've made that clearer in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand the structure of your code, for reasons pointed out by others in the comments. But the basic answer to your question is that you should use `try`-`catch` if you can handle the exceptions gracefully (this typically means you can still return a meaningful result), and let them propagate if not.

So a `ConverterTask` that converted one `String` into another, which may potentially throw exceptions which prevent the conversion from taking place, would look like

```
public class ConverterTask extends Task<String> {

    private final String textToConvert ;

    public ConverterTask(String textToConvert) {
        this.textToConvert = textToConvert ;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        String result = doConversion(textToConvert); // may throw exception...
        return result ;
    }
}
```

and a typical usage would be

```
Executor conversionExec = ... ;

// ...

ConverterTask converterTask = new ConverterTask(someText);
converterTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
    String result = converterTask.getValue();
    // process result...
});
converterTask.setOnFailed(e -> {
    // code to execute in case of unhandled exception...
    // note you can get the exception with
    Throwable thingThatWentWrong = converterTask.getException();
    // ...
});

conversionExec.execute(converterTask);
```

Note that the code in either handler (`onSucceeded` or `onFailed`) is executed on the FX Application Thread for you, so you should not block in those methods, but you can access UI elements.

If you had exceptions from which you could recover you would do something along the lines of

```
@Override
public String call() {
    try {
        String result = doConversion(textToConvert);
        return result ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // fallback computation that doesn't throw exception...
        String result = doSafeConversion(textToConvert);
        return result ;
    }
}
```

and then you don't need the `onFailed` handler.

And obviously if you have some recoverable exceptions and some non-recoverable, you can combine the two techniques:

```
@Override
public String call() throws Exception {

    String partialResult ;
    // recoverable:
    try {
        partialResult = doSomeProcessing(textToConvert);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        partialResult = computeFallbackValue(textToConvert);
    }
    // non-recoverable: may throw exception which is propagated out
    String result = completeComputation(partialResult);
    return result ;
}
```

(and now you need the `onFailed` handler again).

Comment: good to know about teh suceeded/failed handlers i was going to look into jsut that in a bit so you saved me some legwork there. I'm relatively new to javaFX and concurrency in java, so my multiple executor thing my be bad practice and i just wasn't aware, but the executors in my example are in separate fiels so i may spit the code up in the example

Comment: but what you're saying is catch them if you can handle them and still produce a meaningful successful result, otherwise let them bubble up to the application thread and handle them in the failed handler?

Comment: Yes, it's not rocket science: just the usual rules for methods. A method should either exit normally, returning a meaningful result, or it should throw an exception. If your task is a conversion, though, the method should be returning the result of the conversion. You want to make these functional (no shared mutable state, no side effects): just take some immutable state, do a computation, return the result. Throw an exception if you can't complete the task.

Comment: That's what i was thinking, I just wanted to make sure that i wasn't missing a trick while keeping my code lean as the try-catch blocks made the process a mess and all i was doing was printing an error and returning a false when i could just propagate or rethrow